# FloatingActionButton error

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Im trying to use FAB library(https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton), I did as it is written in instructions, but this does not work. What am I doing wrong? Here error that I have:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                         at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                         at
> com.myapp.frags.FirstFragment.onCreateView(FirstFragment.java:91)
>                                                                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
>                                                                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>                                                                         at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                         at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
>                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**My Fragment layout:**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_frg_layout"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mRelative"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
                />
        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>






</RelativeLayout>
```

My Fragment code:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using 3rd party library when there's a FAB from google using the support library?

take a look [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons)

You can attach it to a ListView or Recycler like that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <ListView
              android:id="@+id/lvToDoList"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
              app:layout_anchor="@id/lvToDoList"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can create what ever behaivior you want for the FAB, for example :

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child,
            View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```